# Can m2eclipse work with alternative directory structures?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a legacy  codebase where source  code is not in, for example `src/main/java` per the Maven  standard, but rather in `src`.  Likewise unit-test  source code, output directory, etc.  I cannot change that easily because of the definitions imposed by the framework I work with.

I configure Maven to work with that using `<build><sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>...`

Can M2eclipse be configured to work with that? I want Eclipse to be able to incrementally reload code and in all other ways work closely with the codebase.

Comment: The first thing by migration legacy code is to change the directory strucuture cause otherwise this will never being done...What kind of framework..

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But I wonder if m2eclipse can work with a legacy structure.

Comment: I would suggest to test it...But I recommend to change the structure first...that is the simplest migration path...

Comment: I also have my code in `src` folder instead of `src/main/java` and m2eclipse is working just fine. I think you need to configure your source folders manually in the Java Build Path though.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same scenario and have defined the source directory in each project pom.  However in Eclipse I also had to set it in the Build Path source tab as although it had read the pom, it had created an invalid path to the source.
Once I fixed this up it wored just fine.